# Adding text to textview inside app iPhone

Tags: iphone, textview

I have an app in which I have a textview.  The textview is populated from the first viewcontroller to the detail viewcontroller, and is different depending on which image in the first view is tapped.The user can tap on it and add text and then hide the keyboard.  I would like them to be able to save the added text to the app.  Could someone help me do this or point me in the right direction.

Here is the code from the first view controller.

```
- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:(int)index{

SomeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ((int)index == 0) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(@"This is  #1")
                                                  forKey:@"textkey"];
   }
    else if ((int)index == 1) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(@"This is  #2")
                                                  forKey:@"textkey"];
}
etc.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

On the detailViewController my code is

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad {

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(doneEditing:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;                       //I could use this as the save button.

self.myText.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"textkey"];

}
```

Thanks

---

OK I am trying to get rid of NSUserDefaults and go with an NSMutableDictionary.

Here is my new code in the first view controller where USUserDefault was.

```
- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:(int)index{




SomeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ((int)index == 0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mydictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [mydictionary setObject:(@"0002.jpg") 
                         forKey:@"imagekey"];

    }

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In the detailViewController I have written this code in ViewDidLoad{

```
 imageView .image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[[NSMutableDictionary ] objectForKey:@"imagekey"]];
```

To replace the NSUserDefault code.

but I keep getting errors

Expected ';' after expression
Expected expression
Expession result unused
Expected identifier

Could someone please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "save to the app"?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a good use of the NSUserDefaults class. It's meant for for persistent storage, not inter-class communication. If you do want to keep using it that way, be sure to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after setting a value.

Onto your question...

Since you already have a textview with a text property that contains the current text, you might just want to use that as the storage mechanism. When you instantiate your SomeDetailViewController, just pass the textview.text into a custom init method, or even set the detailViewController.myText.text property directly from your `coverflowView:coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:` implementation.

Comment: Very true: NSUserDefaults saves data to FLASH memory which is 'aging' with every write. I think that checking if app is saving to flash too frequently is even a part of App Store approval process.

Comment: Ok I'm fairly new to this.  Could you show me what you mean in code. By doing it this way would I be getting rid of the current way I am loading my text?

Comment: maybe a better question would be how would you suggest (illustrate) loading the text instead of NSUsersDefaults?

Comment: Ok.  I am thinking of replacing NSUserDefaults with NSMutableDictionary.